# How do I set the Internet Options? Specifically the LAN Settings tick boxes

Tags: windows, networking

I'd like to set the tick box options within the LAN settings of the Internet Options:

[image: LAN Settings screenshot]

I'd prefer the code in a script or C#, but C/C++ would be fine as well. Please answer with the code/script to at least untick the "Use automatic configuration script" option.

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They answer appears to be here if you dont mind using powershell

[Setting Proxy settings in ie using powershell](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/velocity/archive/2007/06/23/setting-proxy-settings-in-ie-using-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the auto config file is stored in this registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL
```

You can use the Registry Functions to access the key: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875(VS.85).aspx